# metric exercises, topology

Tags: general-topology

consider R with the usual metric and $A = (1,2]$ find:

$d(0,A)$

$d(\frac{3}{2}, A)$

$d(1,A)$

$d(Q, A)$

I do not pretend that they do my homework, only that they explain one of these to me with the steps to follow to solve the others since I have found very little information on the subject please.

Comment: What is the definition $d(0, A)$? I'm assuming 0 is a point and $A$ is an interval. Correct?

Answer (score 0):

$d(0,A)= 1$ as $1 \le x$ for all $x \in A$, and as $a_n=\frac{1}{n} + 1 \in A$ and $d(0, a_n)\to 1$ as $ n \to \infty$.

$\frac{3}{2}\in A$ so $d(\frac{3}{2}, A)=0$.

Using the same points $a_n$: $d(a_n,1)=\frac1n \to 0$ so $d(1,A)=0$ and the last one is unclear (what is $Q$?) but $d(\Bbb Q,A)=0$ as witnessed by $\frac{3}{2} \in \Bbb Q \cap A$.

Comment: Thank, very much.